# How do I get FlashBuilder to show me the command-line output?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxmlc

Specifically, I want to know what the commands are... all the flags it produces and passes to mxmlc.  There must be a way, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't think there is a way; but you can guess most of the items if you go through the project properties. I think, other than paths, you'll have to specify most arguments yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimate method - locate mxmlc executable for your platform, then create program with the same name which will log arguments.

If you just want to master mxmlc, there are docs for it and compiler option dump-config: `-dump-config=config.xml`. Config contains almost everything about the project and I used such config to make an automated build.

Answer (score 7):

[The official answer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-59108b2e1215eb9d5e4-8000.html#WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-59108b2e1215eb9d5e4-7ff0):

1. In Flash Builder, select Project > Properties > Flex Compiler
2. In Additional Compiler Arguments, specify the following argument:

   `-dump-config=pathname`, where pathname specifies the absolute path to a file on your system.